# Eliminar último elemento de una lista en C++

Tags: c++, lista

Tengo este programa para trabajar con lista doblemente enlazada en C++.
Lo que funciona mal es la función eliminarfinal, que como su nombre lo indica tendría que eliminar el nodo del final de la lista con su contenido, pero en lugar de hacer eso muestra direcciones de memoria. ¿Cómo puedo solucionar el error?

```
#include<iostream>
#include<windows.h>

using namespace std;

struct lista
{
    int n;
    struct lista *sig, *ant;
}*CAB=NULL, *P=NULL, *AUX=NULL, *F=NULL, *Q=NULL, *QD=NULL, *FD=NULL;


int main (void)
{
    void insertar(void);
    void visualizar();
    void eliminarinicio();
    void eliminarfinal();
    char opc;

    do
    {
        system("cls");
        cout<<"\t|------Operaciones con listas-------|"<<endl;
        cout<<"\t|-----------------------------------|"<<endl;
        cout<<"\t| 1)Insertar                        |"<<endl;
        cout<<"\t| 2)Visualizar                      |"<<endl;
        cout<<"\t| 3)Eliminar al inicio              |"<<endl;
        cout<<"\t| 4)Eliminar al final               |"<<endl;
        cout<<"\t| 0)Salir                           |"<<endl;
        cout<<"\t|-----------------------------------|"<<endl;


        cout<<endl<<endl<<"ingrese una opcion"<<endl;
        opc=std::cin.get();


        system("cls");
        switch (opc)
        {
        case '1':
            insertar();
            break;
        case '2':
            visualizar();
            break;
        case '3':
            eliminarinicio();
            break;
        case '4':
            eliminarfinal();
            break;
        }
    }
    while (opc!='0');
    return 0;
}


void insertar(void)
{
    P=CAB;
    AUX= new lista;
    system("cls");
    cout<<"**************INSERTAR******************"<<endl;
    cout<<"****************************************"<<endl;
    cout<<" Ingrese numero : ";
    cin>>AUX->n;
    F=AUX;
    if (CAB==NULL)
    {
        CAB=AUX;
        P=AUX;
    }
    else
    {
        while (P->sig!=CAB)
        {
            P=P->sig;
        }
    }
    P->sig=AUX;
    AUX->sig=CAB;
    AUX->ant=P;
    CAB->ant=AUX;


}

void visualizar (void) {
    system("cls");
    if(CAB==NULL){
        cout<<"LISTA VACIA";
        getchar();
        return ;
    }
    cout<<"*****LOS NUMEROS INGRESADOS FUERON****"<<endl;
    P=CAB;
    cout<<endl<<"LISTA: "<<endl;
    do{
        cout<<"->"<<P->n<<endl;
        P=P->sig;

    }while (P!=CAB);

    system("pause");
}

void eliminarinicio(void){
    system("cls");
    int valor;
    if(CAB==NULL){
        cout<<"lista vacia"<<endl;
        getchar();
        return;
    }

    cout<<"********ELIMINANDO ELEMENTO********"<<endl;
    system("pause");
    if(CAB!=AUX){
        P=CAB;
        CAB=CAB->sig;
        CAB->ant=AUX;
        AUX->sig=CAB;
        valor=P->n;
        delete P;
        cout<<endl<<"se elimino " <<valor<<" de la lista";
    }else if(CAB==AUX){
        cout<<endl<<"se elimino "<<CAB->n<<", de la lista";
        CAB = NULL;
    }
    getchar();
}

void eliminarfinal(void){ //revisar
    system("cls");
    int valor;
    if(AUX==NULL){
        cout<<"LISTA VACIA"<<endl;
        getchar();
        return;
    }

    cout<<"********ELIMINANDO ELEMENTO********"<<endl;
    system("pause");
    if(AUX!=CAB){
        P=CAB;
        AUX=AUX->ant;
        AUX->sig=CAB;
        CAB->ant=AUX;
        valor=F->n;
        delete F;
        cout<<endl<<"se elimino " <<valor<<" de la lista";
    }else if(AUX==CAB){
        cout<<endl<<"se elimino "<<AUX->n<<", de la lista";
        CAB = NULL;
    }
    getchar();
}
```

Comment: ¿Cuál es el error?

Comment: Como dije, la función eliminarfinal, que como su nombre lo indica tendría que eliminar el nodo del final de la lista con su contenido pero en lugar de hacer eso muestra direcciones de memoria.

Comment: Tienes razón, yo leí mal. Gracias :)

Comment: No entiendo el manejo de punteros que haces. Una lista doblemente enlazada no es una lista circular, son cosas distintas. En una doblemente enlazada el puntero anterior del primer elemento apunta NULL, así sabes cuando termina y cual es el primer elemento (el que el anterior apunte a NULL), y el puntero al siguiente del último apunta a NULL también, y así recorriendo la lista sabes cual es el último. He depurado tu código y no entiendo el lío de punteros. Pero sí veo que el error lo tienes al eliminar el último. Haces F = CAB y luego delete F, eliminando CAB. Por eso falla la visualizacion.

Comment: Primero. No edites el código de la pregunta para responder, responde con nuevo código. Segundo. Está bien la observación y corrección que haces, pero la idea es que en el procedimiento eliminarfinal(void) se utilice la variable P no f. Corregido sería F=AUX; en lugar de F=CAB como aparece en el código.

Answer (score 1):

Como dice el usuario SuperG280, el error del procedimiento se produce al intentar  eliminar el último nodo. Se hace F = CAB y luego delete F, lo cual elimina CAB. Por eso muestra direcciones en memoria en lugar de los contenidos de los nodos.
Una de las soluciones es sustituir P=CAB; por F=CAB;. El código eliminarfinal corregido quedaría así:

```
void eliminarfinal(void){
    system("cls");
    int valor;
    if(AUX==NULL){
        cout<<"LISTA VACIA"<<endl;
        getchar();
        return;
    }

    cout<<"********ELIMINANDO ELEMENTO********"<<endl;
    system("pause");
    if(AUX!=CAB){
        F=CAB;           //<---------- Acá está el cambio, P=CAB; por F=CAB;  
        AUX=AUX->ant;
        AUX->sig=CAB;
        CAB->ant=AUX;
        valor=F->n;
        delete F;
        cout<<endl<<"se elimino " <<valor<<" de la lista";
    }else if(AUX==CAB){
        cout<<endl<<"se elimino "<<AUX->n<<", de la lista";
        CAB = NULL;
    }
    getchar();
}
```

Otra forma de corregir el error sería asignado AUX a P en lugar de hacerlo a CAB como aparee en el código. Quedaría así:

```
void eliminarfinal(void){
    system("cls");
    int valor;
    if(AUX==NULL){
        cout<<"LISTA VACIA"<<endl;
        getchar();
        return;
    }

    cout<<"********ELIMINANDO ELEMENTO********"<<endl;
    system("pause");
    if(AUX!=CAB){
        F=AUX;           //<---------- Acá está el cambio, F=CAB; por F=AUX; 
        AUX=AUX->ant;
        AUX->sig=CAB;
        CAB->ant=AUX;
        valor=F->n;
        delete F;
        cout<<endl<<"se elimino " <<valor<<" de la lista";
    }else if(AUX==CAB){
        cout<<endl<<"se elimino "<<AUX->n<<", de la lista";
        CAB = NULL;
    }
    getchar();
}
```